# Using lodash groupby when your key is an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

Let's say I have an ar of objects like this:

```
var cars = [{
    make: 'audi',
    model: 'r8',
    year: ['2011', '2012']
}, {
    make: 'audi',
    model: 'rs5',
    year: ['2011,', '2013']
}, {
    make: 'ford',
    model: 'mustang',
    year: ['2012', '2013']
}, {
    make: 'ford',
    model: 'fusion',
    year: ['2012', '2015']
}];
```

I want to create an aray of car objects that's grouped by year.

So like..

```
 var cars = [{
        2012: [
            { make: 'audi', model: 'r8' },
            { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang' },
            { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion' }
        ],
        2013: [{ make: 'audi', model: 'rs5' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang' }]
etc..    
}]
```

How can I do this with lodash easily? `groupBy` just groups by the array as it were a string. Seems like a map function is first needed.

Comment: I formatted the code, but I didn't made it valid. Note that a JS array can't have keys like that, you probably want an object literal.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks I edited. Didn't meant to have the keys as string literals.

Comment: You missed the point. You're using an array `[ ]` notation to create an object literal, which should be `{ key: value }`.

Comment: Edited again sorry @EmileBergeron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, unwrap ("linearize") the list and then apply groupBy

```
result = _(cars)
    .flatMap(car => car.year.map(
        year => _.assign({}, car, {year})
    ))
    .groupBy('year')
    .value()
```

This keeps the year field though, don't know if this is a problem.